# Date type property in fields of query_string giving error always

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I have a type in a index which have a property of date type. I need to search by this date in my query_string.

So here is the mapping of that type.

```
    .......
    .......

    "created": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'"'T'"'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    },

    .......
    .......
```

And the query is

```
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": [...... "created", .....],
                    "query": query
                }
```

Now suppose the query has no date, user searched anything else. Still it trying to parse each string with date type and giving error.
And I have tried giving query like ISO date or normal date but every time its giving error that it cant parse.

**I searched "find abcd". Where it should return something. Cause there has record which have abcd in other properties. But it gave this error**

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchParseException: failed to parse date field [find], tried both date format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ], and timestamp number
```

**I have given ISO date 2015-06-08T06:22:09.540Z and got this error**

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse '2015-06-08T06:22:09.540Z': Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 16.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    "^" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:132)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MapperQueryParser.parse(MapperQueryParser.java:887)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:233)
    ... 15 more
```

But when I'm not including the Date type field in the fields of query_string then everything working perfectly.
What should I do now to solve this probm?
I didnt find any related problem in stackoverflow and Elasticsearch The Definitive Guide. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `"lenient": true` in the `"query_string"` to ignore these conversion exceptions:

```
            "query_string": {
                "fields": [...... "created", .....],
                "query": query,
                "lenient": true
            }
```

Quote from [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

> lenient
>
> If set to true will cause format based failures (like providing text to a numeric field) to be ignored.

Related to exact date search, `query_string` treats `:` as a special character and needs to be escaped. Take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) to read more about this:

> If you need to use any of the characters which function as operators in your query itself (and not as operators), then you should escape them with a leading backslash. For instance, to search for (1+1)=2, you would need to write your query as (1+1)\=2.
>
> The reserved characters are: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

Comment: It will solve in case when user will not search by date. But searching by date will not giving any result. Is it not possible?

Comment: That's another issue. Maybe you are searching something that doesn't match or you think it should match.

Comment: no I'm giving a date which have some record to return. But not giving anything. I have searched by giving ISO date normal date everything. In that case again that parsing failure is showing

Comment: What format is this `"format": "yyyy-MM-dd'"'T'"'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`? I tried adding it in Sense and it fails. Why don't you use in the mapping one of the ones ES is providing? For example `date_time`. The one you have complains about `'"'T'"'` (I think you have too many quotes in there).

Comment: That format is the same what you will get when you run this script. var date=new Date(); echo d.toISOString().  And sorry it was my mistake the query is searching by date.. When I'm searching like this "from 06 june to 08 june" its working. I think it is not possible to search by a specific date in es? is it?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. You need to escape the `:` character.

Comment: you will not believe but "from 06 june to 08 june" was working. But now after server restart its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79962/discussion-between-jayadratha-mondal-and-andrei-stefan).